# Why RuntimeBinderException is not caught?

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

I understand why it is being thrown, but why is it still unhandled when I have a catch block for it? Please see attached image for details.

```
try
{
    // Exception is thrown at the following line as not all items have Id property
    addedLabours = currentLabours.Where(c => !previousLabours.Select(p => (Guid)p.Id).Contains((Guid)c.Id)); 
}
catch (RuntimeBinderException) 
{
    addedLabours = currentLabours;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Google "linq deferred execution".  You can append `.ToList()` to get it to bomb early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got an answer from one of my colleagues:

"Because it's deferred execution. The lamba are executed outside this context as deep down there are still IQueryables. The basis of IQueryables is an Expression that is constructed but executed at a different point.

If the lamba in the where clause was inside {} you could put the try {} catch (RuntimeBinderException) and it would get caught. But not outside the lamba."

Aside from understanding the reason it's possible to catch it by appending the `.ToList()` (thanks Hans Passant!).

```
try
{
    // Exception will be caught with .ToList()
    addedLabours = currentLabours.Where(c => !previousLabours.Select(p => (Guid)p.Id).Contains((Guid)c.Id)).ToList(); 
}
catch (RuntimeBinderException) 
{
    addedLabours = currentLabours;
}
```